# How can I tell programmatically whether a process is in app-nap?

Tags: macos, script, app-nap

I'm looking for a script, built-in shell command, or program (with sources) that can tell me whether a process is in App-nap mode or not.

I want to use it in automated testing, for profiling and to make sure my App uses all available energy conservation technology correctly.